# SVG Linear gradient, UserSpaceOnUse

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to get a linear gradient to work with `gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'` but for some reason the gradient is not applied.Take a look at the following code.

```
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="user-grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
              <stop stop-color="orange" offset="0"></stop>
              <stop stop-color="blue" offset="1"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="object-grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">
              <stop stop-color="orange" offset="0"></stop>
              <stop stop-color="blue" offset="1"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" fill="url(#user-grad)"/>
    <rect x="250" y="0" width="200" height="100" fill="url(#object-grad)"/> 
</svg>
```

The first rect has the gradientUnits attribute applied and the second one does not. The gradient works well the second one but not the first one. How do I get the first one to look like the second one
[image]

Comment: Try `<linearGradient id="user-grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">` or `<linearGradient id="user-grad" x2="100%"  gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">`

Comment: different unit are different but you're using the same values. If you had something that was 1cm and you changed the units to 1km would you expect it to look the same? You need to use values appropriate to the units you've picked.

Comment: @enxaneta Yes that definitely get's it close but there is still a slight difference(The blue on the right is missing). Ideally I would prefer getting both to look exactly the same. Is there a way that can be done

Comment: For the same result you can use `x2="200"` or `x2="40%"` since the width of the rect (200) represents 40% of 500

Comment: userSpaceUnits are viewBox units - which in your case, you've set equal to pixels. So that x1="0" and x2="1" means that the gradient spans from pixel 0 to pixel 1 on the x axis - leaving the other 199 pixels equal to the final stop color.

Answer (score 0):

It works like a charm but one needs to fiddle with the coordinates to get it right since *“userSpaceOnUse”* starts further in than *“objectBoundingBox”*, according to Mozilla.

See their pattern demo comparing the two methods here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/patternUnits

The theory of how they operate differently is explained here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientUnits

Anyway, if you change your coordinates like below it works fine…

```
<linearGradient id="user-grad" x1="180" y1="80" x2="0" y2="80" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
```

Btw, I doubt this attribute/parameter had gradients in mind but it does make sense with patterns etc.